# Facebook Authorization for an iFrame App in PHP

Tags: php, facebook

I need to get the User ID of a user hitting a Facebook iFrame application. While sifting through all of the bogus and outdated information, I think I've come across the correct info.

When the user hits the page, I need to have them authorize the app. In my PHP I do this:

```
$facebook = new Facebook($appData);
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if(!$user) {
    echo '<script>top.location.href="'.$facebook->getLoginUrl().'";</script>';
    die();
}
```

This gives me the authorization request, but then pushes me back to my server, not the iFrame App's URL (http://app.facebook.com/blah). I manually constructed the URL and tried to set the URL to the app.facebook.com URI but then it I get an error saying the URL is not valid for the app.

How do you get it to redirect back to the app after authorization? This app will live inside Facebook, not be generally accessible outside, so I'm not looking for Facebook Connect login.

**Edit**

This is the exact error I get when I fiddle with the request_uri:

```
API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried setting the `redirect_uri` parameter.

```
if(!$user) {
  $params = array('redirect_uri' => 'http://app.facebook.com/blah/');
  die('<script>top.location.href="'.$facebook->getLoginUrl($params).'";</script>');
}
```

Comment: Yes, I tried that. I get the error I added under 'Edit'. As far as I know the app is set up correctly. If I remove the authorization bits the app displays in the Facebook iFrame just fine under the app.facebook.com/blah URL

Comment: What happens when you try to run the code sample listed above?

Comment: That's actually where I learned about using the <script> redirect instead using the header() redirect. It does the same thing.

Comment: Then your app is more than likely misconfigured. See @squinlans answer.

Comment: I had the redirect_uri set to `http://apps.facebook.com/blah` and did not have a '/' at the end. That's enough to stop it from working correctly.

Comment: Yeah. Been there before. Sorry I didn't check for that sooner.

Answer (score 0):

Go to:

```
http://developers.facebook.com/apps
```

In the your developer application settings on you need to change the URL settings so that Facebook knows your app is a canvas app. In the settings, be sure to delete all the URLs that are in the **Web** tab and then make sure that all the URLs are appropriately set in the **On Facebook** tab.

Comment: 'Web' is empty, and on the 'On Facebook' -> 'Canvas Settings' page I have the Canvas Page filled in with 'blah', and Canvas URL filled in with the location on my web server that contains the app. Nothing else is filled in.

Answer (score 0):

You can following sample code to authorize facebook application in an iframe app using graph api

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

/*
 * App Config
*/
$config=    array(
            'appId'  => 'APPID',
            'secret' => 'APPSECRET',
            'canvas'=>"http://apps.facebook.com/sampleapp/");


$GRAPH_URL  = "https://graph.facebook.com/";
$scope      = "publish_stream,email";
$auth_url   = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=".$config['appId']."&redirect_uri=".urlencode($config['canvas']). "&scope=" . $scope;


$signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];

list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 
$data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

if(is_array($data)){
    $authToken  =   $data['oauth_token'];
    $userId     =   $data['user_id'];
    $_SESSION['auth_token'] =   $authToken;

    //check for permission//
    $permissions = json_decode(curl_get_file_contents($GRAPH_URL . "me/permissions?access_token=" . $authToken), TRUE);
    if(array_key_exists('publish_stream', $permissions['data'][0]) ) {
        $post   =   array('client_id'=>$config['appId'],'redirect_uri'=>$config['canvas'].'','client_secret'=>$config['secret'],'type'=>'client_cred');     
        $token_url="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token";
        $response = curlpost($token_url,$post);
        $params = explode('&',$response);       
        if(isset($params[0])){
            $token  =   explode('=',$params[0]);
            if($token[0]=='access_token'){
                $access_token = $token[1];
                $_SESSION['access_token']=$access_token;
                $_SESSION['authorized']=1;      
                echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $config['canvas']."home.php'; </script>");    
            }
        }else{
            echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $config['canvas']."error.php'; </script>");   
        }   


    }else{    
        $url='https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id='.$config['appId'].'&redirect_uri='.urlencode($config['canvas']).'&display=page&scope=publish_stream,email&type=user_agent';
        echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $url. "'</script>");      
    }


}else{
    echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $config['canvas']."error.php';</script>");        
}


?>
```

Check this link for details

http://forum.bharathlisting.com/showthread.php?tid=13&pid=20#pid20